# Why does a select query require an IX lock?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, deadlock

While inspecting the deadlock graph below, I found that a `SELECT` query (only query inside the SP being executed by the first process `process569f048`) and an `UPDATE` query forming a deadlock; and the `SELECT` query is requiring an `IX` lock.

In what situation such locks are necessary for a `SELECT`? What can I do to avoid the deadlock?

Here is the `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT TOP (@p_takeCount)
     t.Id
    ,s.Column2
    ,t.STATUS
    ,t.Column3
    ,t.Column4
FROM Table2 t WITH (INDEX (IX_Table2))
INNER JOIN Table1 s ON s.Id = t.ParentId
WHERE t.STATUS != 0
    AND t.Column5 IS NULL
    AND s.SomeId = @p_someId
    AND s.Category = 2
ORDER BY t.id
```

Here is the plan:

[image]

Here is the `UPDATE` query:

```
update Table2
set [Status] = @0, Column5 = null, Column6 = @1
where ([Id] = @2)
```

Here is the plan:
[image]

Here is the deadlock graph:

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process569f048" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process569f048" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 5:1:3017144" waittime="2867" ownerId="964271246" transactionname="SELECT" lasttranstarted="2017-01-29T10:10:49.643" XDES="0x800f9d20" lockMode="S" schedulerid="10" kpid="10108" status="suspended" spid="70" sbid="2" ecid="2" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2017-01-29T10:10:49.643" lastbatchcompleted="2017-01-29T10:10:49.643" clientapp="EntityFramework" hostname="LOCALHOST" hostpid="4936" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="964271246" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="" line="17" stmtstart="1298" stmtend="1954" sqlhandle="0x03000500d21f5e3dd6d19700cca400000100000000000000" />
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf />
    </process>
    <process id="process8ee3dc8" taskpriority="0" logused="17956" waitresource="PAGE: 5:1:3017343" waittime="2864" ownerId="964271345" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2017-01-29T10:10:49.667" XDES="0xafdbb03b0" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="17" kpid="9468" status="suspended" spid="61" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2017-01-29T10:10:49.703" lastbatchcompleted="2017-01-29T10:10:49.703" clientapp="EntityFramework" hostname="LOCALHOST" hostpid="20696" loginname="dbuser_d" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="964271345" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="" line="1" stmtstart="74" sqlhandle="0x02000000403aaa03bd8879de1c73d49641f1f81b6ca095af" />
        <frame procname="" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" />
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
        (@0 tinyint,@1 varchar(64),@2 bigint)update [dbo].[Table2]
        set [Status] = @0, [Column5] = null, [Column6] = @1
        where ([Id] = @2)
      </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="3017144" dbid="5" objectname="" id="lockc296c6380" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594073317376">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process8ee3dc8" mode="IX" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process569f048" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="3017343" dbid="5" objectname="" id="lockd33965a80" mode="S" associatedObjectId="72057594073317376">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process569f048" mode="S" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process8ee3dc8" mode="IX" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Index details:

```
[PK_Table2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC);
[IX_Table2]([Column5] ASC, [Status] ASC) INCLUDE ( [Id],[ParentId],[Column3],[Column4]) WHERE ([Column5] IS NULL);
```

Object with id `72057594073317376` (`associatedObjectId`) is: `[IX_Table2]`

Comment: what happens if you remove the `WITH (INDEX (IX_Table2))` from the select query? your select is explicitly locking the index on that table. I'd test it without the explicit lock.

Comment: If I remove the hint, the plan shows a _clustered index scan_ on `Table2`.

Comment: Could you post DDL of the tables?

Comment: `process569f048` is the `select` statement and only showing S locks. In that deadlock graph the `select` is not asking for any `IX` locks.

Comment: @SeanGallardy Please check the `waiter-list` in the `resource-list`:  <waiter `id="process8ee3dc8" mode="IX" requestType="wait" />`

Comment: @mshsayem Exactly... and that's the `UPDATE` statement NOT the `SELECT` statement, so the select is not asking for an `IX` the update is. Again, as I said, the select statement is not taking an `IX` lock thus the statement in your question "the SELECT query is requiring an IX lock." is incorrect and I'm attempting to point you to out of order resource use and not some weird isolation level locking use.

Comment: @SeanGallardy Thanks! I can understand now. It is saying that, they are waiting for two _PAGE_s which are locked in incompatible modes by each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deadlock occurs because of two queries crabbing the pages. SELECT has page 3017343 in S mode and wants page 3017144 in S mode. UPDATE has page 3017144  in IX and wants page 3017343 in IX mode. This is typical symptom of abusing tables as queues (hint: Status column). See [Using Tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) for how this is modeled correctly, avoiding deadlocks. Separate events form state.

Answer (score 2):

Looking the deadlock graph, the SELECT command (process569f048) actually takes a shared lock "S", which is the default lock held by a process reading data. The UPDATE COMMAND, does indeed take the intent lock "IX".

Checkout this [Technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Reads under the default isolation level require brief locks to ensure transactional consistency (with caveats -- see Locking Read Committed Behaviours at https://sqlperformance.com/2014/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-committed-isolation-level).

In your case it seems the likely deadlock cause is that the write query needs to update multiple indexes, and the read query has already locked certain rows in the non-clustered index -- or vice-versa.
So it's possible that removing the hint that Tanner noticed may resolve it (since the update and select can then queue politely).The hint *may* not be necessary if the data remains small enough, since after all SQL Server determines by default that a single scan will be more efficient than a bunch of parallel seeks.

Some more ways to resolve this:

If your select query is ok with inaccurate/incomplete data (and still the occasional crash due to data movement), use read uncommitted isolation, or nolock on the joins. But read this first: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-uncommitted-isolation-level

If Snapshot Isolation is enabled on your database, and your select query is ok with not seeing updates currently being made (i.e. being milliseconds "out of date"), then use that for just this select query if you can. (There are further considerations if the select query is part of a transaction, or if there is more DML after the select.)
(And don't confuse this with Read Committed Snapshot Isolation which would also solve your issue but requires comprehensive review before being enabled.)

If the problem is relatively rare, perhaps just implement a deadlock retry in the app code where your queries are called.
Or if you are using stored procs you can also to it there, see "Retries in TRY/CATCH" at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175791(v=sql.80).aspx -- to which I would add that if you also use SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY N'LOW' before the retry loop then the deadlock retry need only be implemented for your select statement, which also simplifies the loop code (no rollback etc.).

Comment: Well, if the `SELECT` query have already locked the index (single index) which is required for the `UPDATE` query, then the `UPDATE` query should just _block_; why the _deadlock_? That was the original question; why the `SELECT` query is asking for an `IX` lock (after it has acquired the `S` lock)?

Comment: His select query is only asking for S locks, not IX.

Comment: Sorry mshsayem, didn't notice you were the original poster. I now see you've understood from others.  
  
By the way, Sean Gallardy is correct that out of order resource use is the root cause and may be worth fixing, but it may be difficult to control consistently and might not be worth it if the problem is occasional. My general "weird isolation level locking use" suggestions leverage system features that have been provided in part to work around or avoid such problems, so there's nothing weird about using them.